# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number' error

Tags: angular, angular10

I am using this code in angular in component HTML file. But when ng serve then error is showing

**Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'**

How to solve this issue

My angular html code is

```
<input type="text" #age (keyup)="0" />

<div *ngIf="age.value>18 ; else elseblock">
    You are elegable for vote
</div>

<ng-template #elseblock>
    <div>You are not elegable for vote</div>
</ng-template>
```

Error is

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:88:17 - error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
>
> 88     <div *ngIf="age.value>18 ; else elseblock">
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/app.component.ts:9:16
> 9   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Comment: can you show the code filling `age` variable ? If from backend, show the JSON ?

Comment: That code is already here: `#age` on the input. It just doesn't quite do what OP expects ...

Comment: @Random: `age` is the template reference variable of the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<input>` by default provides values of type string. You could explicitly convert it to a number to perform the comparison.

```html
<input type="text" #age (keyup)="0" />

<div *ngIf="+age.value > 18; else elseblock">     <!-- notice the '+' -->
  You are elegable for vote
</div>

<ng-template #elseblock>
  <div>You are not elegable for vote</div>
</ng-template>
```

<sup>You could also have `type="number"` since age must be a number but it wouldn't help with the comparison without explicit type casting.</sup>

Comment: Are you casting to _number_ by applying unary plus or what is going on here?

Comment: @AndreKR: Sorry for the delayed response. And yes, the unary plus is used to cast to number. Refer relevant [`ECMA Spec`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.6).